# has_changed() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'initial' and 'data'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to prevent the user from meddling with a hidden form field by checking in the view like so:

```py
if form.fields["email"].has_changed():
    form.add_error(
        "email",
        ValidationError(
            "Email does not correspond to user", code="invalid_email",
        ),
    )
```

but I get the following TypeError:

> has_changed() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'initial' and 'data'

At this point, `form` is a "bound form" which has gone through the user and a POST request, by the way.

Inspecting the function itself, it does seem to have two non-optional parameters, but the documentation does not mention these at all, and it's not too clear to me what I should pass anyway: if I have to provide the initial value and the new value myself, I could just compare those by myself with no need for this method. What am I missing?

*It also occurred to me that I just need to set the field as disabled and any changed value would be ignored, but I'm still curious nonetheless.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting my code more thoroughly I noticed that at the moment I did the has_changed() check, validation had not yet been run on the form. Once moved after a `form.is_valid()` check, has_changed() worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it is a bound form makes not much difference. The `form.fields` is a dictionary that maps strings on form fields. The [**`has_changed`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/fields.py#L174-L191) for a field is used by the form to determine if the value has indeed changed.

You can check if a value has changed, by inspecting the `changed_data` dictionary:

```
if 'email' in form.changed_data:
    form.add_error(
        "email",
        ValidationError(
            "Email does not correspond to user", code="invalid_email",
        ),
    )
```